# Why we say 'the mountains' with definite article

Tags: grammatical-number, articles, definite-articles

There are rules for zero/definite/indefinite article.
And I don't get why we use 'the' with word 'mountains' in the next sentence:

*I like to spend holidays in **the mountains**.*

As for me the correct rule for this case is *speaking about things in general*, which states that we should use no article (zero article), like in 'I afraid of spiders.'

So why we use 'the' + 'mountains' ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Definite and indefinite articles when referring to generic abstract objects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266664/definite-and-indefinite-articles-when-referring-to-generic-abstract-objects) ''You can take your kids to the zoo."

... [is idiomatic], not [necessarily] because 'zoo' has already been mentioned [previously] ... : it is equally acceptable to use the definite article in expressions like

"We're going to the seaside." / 

"We went to the opera three times last year." / 

"We often go to the cinema''.

Comment: We can see that usage of articles is not strictly due to logic by observing that some other languages (with definite and indefinite articles) do this in another way.  There is even some disagreement between US and UK on some of these ... I went to school, I went to the school.  They sent me to hospital, They sent me to the hospital.

Comment: Neither of them actually, but this reveals something...
https://englishwithkim.com/definite-article-places-spaces/
I think, by far, that in British English most of idiomatic places are supplied with 'the', except some of them like hospital, jail, university, school, church and may be some more of them. So the opera, the cinema (but, these ones are besides incountable), the beach, the mountains. 'The with places' rule is nothing about 'Zero article with things in general, or conceptual places like "home"'. And yes, articles subject is complex and full of special cases.

Comment: Mountains are a feature of local weather, like clouds and snow. In Seattle, which lies on a sound between the Olympic range to the west and the Cascade range to the east, one says _The mountains are out_ or _The Olympics/Cascades are out_ when they're visible, depending. Seattle is also close to Mt. Rainier, which towers over everything when it's visible, in which case the local phrase is _The Mountain is out_ -- singular, and you can almost hear the capital letter.

Comment: And the difference between 'go to a restaurant' and 'go to the beach' is, according to the lessons I study now, is because despite 'beach' is countable and sounds abstract, we always know which particular beach we are talking about. We have this particular beach in mind. Which is not true for a random abstract restaurant (and mountains). I may be wrong, yes it's complex.

Comment: Well, that’s not really the case. “We always know” is an effort to make this usage fit, which it really doesn’t. Consider “Whenever I visit a foreign city, I like to go to the theater.”