# an atom vs the atom

Tags: formality, definite-articles, indefinite-articles, science, academic-writing

In Britannica's Atom term, some general sentences about an atom use "an atom", and others "the atom", why?

Sentences with "**an** atom":

> The behaviour of **an** atom is strongly influenced by these orbital properties, and its chemical properties are determined by orbital groupings known as shells.

> As noted in the introduction to this article, **an** atom consists largely of empty space.

Sentences with "**the** atom":

> As such, **the** atom is the basic building block of chemistry.

> Most of **the** atom is empty space.

Thanks

**Edit:**

The [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-choosing-the-definite-vs-indefinite-vs-none-a) does not answer my question, because in the same case of Atom (in meaning of all atoms) sometimes uses "the'' and sometimes "an''. Maybe the writer wants to emphasize by use of "the" and "an", to say it is a general case of an Atom? (Because, "the" may say specific atom, and "an" may say one of the atoms and not all, but when "the" and "an" use together for general Atom meaning, reader understand 100% that it all atoms) If this is the writer meaning, should we use this style in our formal writing?
[image]
[Atom in Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/atom)

Comment: I'd say (without more context) that the articles are interchangeable here (though consistency is a factor that needs to be considered).

Comment: See [apaderno's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2032/18696) at the linked question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, how it answer my question? "an" an atom consists.., and in other "the"  the atom is empty space.. Both sentences speak about all atoms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, please see my edit

Comment: See my answer at [Definite and indefinite articles when referring to generic abstract {ie notional examples} objects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266664/definite-and-indefinite-articles-when-referring-to-generic-abstract-objects).